# django model - fetching user data accross multiple tables

Tags: django

I am writing a django (1.10) website and using allauth for authorisations. I don't want to extend the user model in django - because allauth adds a further layer of complexity to what is already a seemingly convoluted process.

I want to create a model (Custom UserManager?) that will have the following methods:

1. get_all_subscriptions_for_user(user=specified_user)
2. get_unexpired_subscriptions_for_user(user=specified_user)

**Note:** unexpired subscriptions are defined by subscriptions whose end_date > today's date.

This is a snippet of my models.py below

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
#...

class Subscription(models.Model):
    token = models.CharKey()
    start_date = models.DateTime()
    end_date   = models.DateTime()
    # other attributes


class UserSubscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription)



# In view
def foo(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    # how can I implement the following methods:
    # get_all_subscriptions_for_user(user=specified_user)
    # get_unexpired_subscriptions_for_user(user=specified_user)
```

Ideally, I would like to have a custom user manager, which can fetch this data in one trip to the database - but I'm not sure if I can have a custom user manager without having a custom user model.

**[[Aside]]**

I'm trying to avoid using a custom model, because it wreaks havoc on the other applications (in my project) which have User as a FK. `makemigrations` and `migrate` always barf with a message about **inconsistent migration history**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with a custom `Manager`, don't need a `UserManager` since you are fetching related models:

```
class UserSubscriptionManager(models.Manager):

    def for_user(self, user):
        return super(UserSubscriptionManager, self).get_queryset().filter(user=user)

    def unexpired_for(self, user):
        return self.for_user(user).filter(
            suscription__end_date__gt=datetime.date.today()  # import datetime 
        )
```

in your models:

```
class UserSubscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription)

    user_objects = UserSubscriptionManager()
```

this way you can do chain filters in the view, for example:

```
 unexpired_suscriptions = UserSubscription.user_objects().unexpired_for(
    user=request.user
 ).exclude(suscription__token='invalid token')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
response = []
user_sub = UserSubscription.objects.filter(user=user.pk)
for row in user_sub:
        subscription = Subscription.objects.get(pk=row.subscription)
        end_date = subscription.end_date
        if end_date > timezone.now():
             response.append(subscription)
```